# Ways to express proc inside a method

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

I'm interested in seeing different ways the proc can be expressed inside a method that takes args.

This method is meant to be a sort of FizzBuzz that will dynamically replace "Fizz" or "Buzz" as well as the traditional divisors 3 & 5.

```
def fizz_buzz_custom(string_1="Fizz", string_2="Buzz", num_1=3, num_2=5)
  proc do |length|
    index = length + 1 
    val = if (index % 3 == 0 && index & 5 == 0)
      (string_1+string_2)
    elsif index % 3 == 0
      string_1
    elsif index % 5 == 0
      string_2      
    else
      index
    end
  end
end
```

Here are some examples with test output:

```
fizz_buzz_custom[15]                         # returns 16
fizz_buzz_custom[44]                         # returns "FizzBuzz" (45 is divisible by 3 and 5)
fizz_buzz_custom('Hey', 'There')[25]         # returns 26
fizz_buzz_custom('Hey', 'There')[11]         # returns "Hey" (12 is divisible by 3)
fizz_buzz_custom("What's ", "up?", 3, 7)[80] # returns "What's " (81 is divisible by 3)
```

Comment: Have you searched Code Review (and SO) for "Ruby Fizzbuzz"?  One gets umpteen hits.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't actually put the fizzbuzz tag on this post, that was Jamal the moderator, my question is much less to do with fizzbuzz and much more to do with procs. - Also, yes I have searched for similar implementations, but the results were not satisfactory, thats why I posted here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can express a proc/block/lambda as

```
Proc.new do |...|
# or
lambda do |...|
# or
-> (...) do
```

Either syntax (and your current one) should work fine for this. To invoke the block, you can use square brackets like now, or use `call`.

Really, that's about it, unless I'm misinterpreting your question.

However, I see some other issues with your code:

- Use a hash for the arguments. Please. The current construction is very un-Ruby-like. A hash will also "force" you to write the method (or block, in this case) in a more generic manner, since a hash can have any number of key/value pairs.
- Why `length`? It's just a number. Whose to say it's the length of anything?
- Also, why add 1 to `length`? Just wondering. If anything, going from an array's length to an index usually involves *subtracting* 1.

Something like this seems cleaner (though it's as much about FizzBuzz as it is about procs):

```
def custom_fizz_buzz(divisors = {"Fizz" => 3, "Buzz" => 5})
  divisors = divisors.sort_by { |_, value| value }
  -> (number) do
    output = divisors.map { |key, value| key if (number % value).zero? }.compact.join
    output.empty? ? number : output
  end
end
```

which'll give you

```
custom_fizz_buzz[7]                              # => 7
custom_fizz_buzz.call(9)                         # => "Fizz"
custom_fizz_buzz[15]                             # => "FizzBuzz"
custom_fizz_buzz("What's " => 3, "up?" => 7)[21] # => "What's up?"
```

or even

```
1.upto(100).map(&custom_fizz_buzz) # => [1, 2, "Fizz", 4, "Buzz", .... etc.]
```